# Previously stored strings are overwritten by fgets

Tags: c, csv, fgets, strtok

I'm reading records from a CSV file using fgets() to read the file one line at a time, and strtok() to parse the fields in each line. I'm encountering a problem where fgets() overwrites a string that was previously written, in favor of the new string. 
Here's an example of what I mean by that:

record.csv (This is the file I'm reading in)

```
John,18
Johann,29
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct customer {
    char *name;
    int age;
} Customer;

int main(void) 
{
    FILE *csv_data;
    char line[100], *token;
    Customer newData[2];

    csv_data = fopen("record.csv", "r");
    // Index 0 for John's data, index 1 for Johann's data
    int i = 0;

    /* loops until end of file */
    while(fgets(line, 100, csv_data)) {

        /* name field */
        token = strtok(line, ",");
        if (token != NULL) {
            newData[i].name = token;        
        }

        /* age field */
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        if (token != NULL) {
            // atoi() converts ascii char to integer
            newData[i].age = atoi(token);
        }
        i++;
    }
    /* print John's records */
    printf("%s\n", newData[0].name);
    printf("%d\n", newData[0].age);

    /* print Johann's records */
    printf("%s\n", newData[1].name);
    printf("%d\n", newData[1].age);

    return 0;
}
```

When we compile and execute this, it prints out:

```
Johann
18
Johann 
29
```

"John" in `newData[0].name` gets overwritten with "Johann" during the second iteration of the `while` loop. Notice however that only the strings get mixed up, but not the integers. I suspect this has to do with `fgets` because when I modified the above source to only run `fgets` once, the output for "John" was as it should be.
Maybe I'm misusing `fgets` (or perhaps my assumption is wrong), but could someone give me some pointers on why the strings are being overwritten with each calls to `fgets`?

Second Update: Thank-you very much again to all the commenters and the answerers. Good to know those things which I was not aware of. The source works perfect now.

Comment: You copy each line over the same variable `line`; you don't make a copy of the data found by `strtok`.  That's how the overwriting occurs.  Allocate space and copy the data, maybe using `strdup()`.  C doesn't manage the memory for strings for you; you have to do it for yourself.

Comment: @xing, ohh, memory for `newData[i].name` has to be allocated manually in the heap? I was not aware of that. Thanks, I'll try it.
@JonathanLeffler so `newData[i].name = token` doesn't copy the data?

Comment: you can allocate memory for the name by changing this: `newData[i].name = token;` to this: `newData[i].name = strdup(token);`.

Comment: Thanks @bruceg. Yep, I implemented `strdup` and it copied over the strings just as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not copy the string but the pointer to the string.

A very simple way to copy the string, but note that this limit the size of the string at 99 characters.

```
typedef struct customer {
    char name[100];
    int age;
} Customer;

strcpy(newData[i].name, token);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
newData[i].name = malloc( strlen( token ) + 1 );
strcpy( newData[i].name, token );
```

or define `name` member as `char name[64];` and then again `strcpy( newData[i].name, token );` without `malloc`. The 64 bytes for name can be more or less.