# fgets loop only works properly if string is malloc'd again at the end of the loop

Tags: c, malloc, fgets

I have to read in comma separated lines from a file, break down the args between that commas, and handle them accordingly. I have the following code set up to do exactly what I need:

```
char *string = malloc(MAX_INPUT);
char * current_parent;
char * current_child;
// while there are still lines to read from the file
while(fgets(string, BUFF_SIZE, file) != NULL){
          // get the parent of a line and its first child
          current_parent = trim(strtok(string, ","));

          if(strcmp(current_parent, "") != 0){

                 current_child = trim(strtok(NULL, ","));

                 if(current_child == NULL || strcmp(current_child, "") == 0){
                           tree = add_child(tree, current_parent, "");
                 }
                 else{
                           while(current_child != NULL){
                                  tree = add_child(tree, current_parent, current_child);
                                  current_child = trim(strtok(NULL, ","));
                           }
                 }
                 current_parent = 0;
                 current_child = 0;

         }
         string = (char *)malloc(MAX_INPUT);
}
// close the file
free(string);
fclose(file);
```

Example of a file:

```
john 1, sam 2
sam 2, ben 4, frances, sam 3
ben 4, sam 4, ben 5, nancy 2, holly
ben 5, john 2, sam 5
```

Whatever is before the first comma is the parent's name, and all other strings after that are its children's names.

My problem is that for whatever reason it only reads in the data properly if I malloc the string all over again at the end of the loop. In addition to this, if I try to free the memory before malloc'ing again, it doesn't work - resulting in memory leaks. I've even tried setting up the loop to just use a fixed sized string, but it still then reads in this jumbled data at the end. I've also tried manually emptying string at the end of each loop. I have a feeling that I may be overlooking something really simple but this has been driving me crazy. Let me know if I can provide anything else that would be of help. Thanks.

Edit: Not sure if this is important for anything but MAX_INPUT and BUFF_SIZE are both 1024

Comment: What happens to `current_parent` behind the scenes? It might start with the same pointer value as `string`, from `current_parent = trim(strtok(string, ","));`, but if it gets `free`d then `string` is no longer any use. What does `trim()` do?

Comment: @WeatherVane it isn't freed anywhere behind the scenes and it isn't manipulated at all aside from that line

Comment: Suspect damage somewhere else in the program, perhaps use a memory usage tool. How does it work if you remove all the tree operations and just print the strings extracted?

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that you are not putting the strings into the tree, only pointers to the string, which you then overwrite with the next line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Previously stored strings are overwritten by fgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790786/previously-stored-strings-are-overwritten-by-fgets)